# Negative latitude after calculation position from tile

Tags: javascript, mapping, gis, openstreetmap

I generate tiles from Geoserver and I want to get Lat/Lon from tile file name. I use the following functions from (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#ECMAScript_(JavaScript/ActionScript,_etc)

```
function tile2long(x,z) {
  return (x/Math.pow(2,z)*360-180);
 }
 function tile2lat(y,z) {
  var n=Math.PI-2*Math.PI*y/Math.pow(2,z);
  return (180/Math.PI*Math.atan(0.5*(Math.exp(n)-Math.exp(-n))));
 }
```

For Lon I get the expected value but for Lat the value is negative number (Which I think is not right). What's the reason for that ? (The projection I use to generate the tile is EPSG:3857)

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you think negative latitude is incorrect? A you see in https://epsg.io/3857, it is allowed (usually it is the south hemisphere)

Comment: I thought so , because OSM site shows this coordinate as positive number (as seen in the image).. I am in the Northern hemisphere (Sofia , Bulgaria)